# How to squash a lot of commits automatically?

Tags: git, commit, squash

I have a lot of commits that I want to squash together into one commit. Of course I may replace `pick` with `squash` for every commit, but I have a hundreds commits.
Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Which editor are you using to edit this list of commits? There's probably a global search and replace command available to you. For example in vim you might use `:%s/pick/squash/g`

Comment: You can use the `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` variable to do that. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27697274/974186

Comment: Would you like to keep all of the commit messages?  If you don't mind entering a new commit message, there is an easy way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a sequence of commits

```
... - C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 - C5 <- HEAD
```

and you want to squash `C2` to `C5` into a single commit, you can reset your branch to `C1` while keeping the state of your working directory and staging area, ans then commit again:

```
git reset --soft C1
git commit
```

This will require you to re-enter a commit message.  You can of course use `git log` before resetting and copy the parts of the commit messages you want to keep.

If you want to squash a feature branch into a single commit ontop of the `master` branch, another option is to use the `--squash` option to `git merge`.